# How to find different values of duplicate values in the same table from two columns of that table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table of products where the same product code have various different values and some have matching values. I want to get the result for the products which have various different values.

I tried using distinct it works but it also gives me the unique values

```
Ex : 

Prod      |      Amount 
1100005          10
1100005          15
1100005          25
1100001          10
1100001          10
1100001          10
1100002          9 
1100002          8
1100002          7
1100003          54
1100003          54
```

I want the result as follows : -

```
Prod      |      Amount 
1100005          10
1100005          15
1100005          25
1100002          9 
1100002          8
1100002          7
```

Comment: Why is 1100003 - 54 combination not in result set?

Comment: Sorry. mistake by me

Comment: @Littlefoot: (1100003, 54) is duplicated in the data. OP only wants the combinations which are not duplicated.

Answer (score 2):

`COUNT(*)` and `HAVING` will be your friend here:

```
SELECT PROD, AMOUNT
  FROM SOME_TABLE
  GROUP BY PROD, AMOUNT
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
  ORDER BY PROD, AMOUNT
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d5661c04411202a4f1250261f76dff60)

Answer (score 1):

use aggregation and `exists`

```
select  prod,amount
from table t1
group by prod,amount
having count(*)=1
and exists ( select 1 from table t2 where t1.prod=t2.prod
           having count(*)>1
            )
```

Comment: It is still coming with the unique values i don't need the unique values

Comment: Dear, Still the result is coming with the unique values

Comment: @Netfoxf https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=245fdfc49954d6472247c33a66380c5d here is the link where tested show where you are not seeing your result

Comment: https://imgur.com/zHv2EBF

I have taken screen shot here; i already sorted by ascending in prod

Comment: @Netfoxf add your data in my link and show where its not worked?

Comment: This solution uses SQL Server syntax even though the question is tagged `[oracle]`.

Answer (score 0):

How about just using aggregation?

```
select prod, amount
from t
group by prod, amount
having count(*) = 1;
```

This returns the prod/amount pairs that appear only once.

If you want prods *all* of whose `amounts` are different, then:

```
select prod_amount
from (select prod, amount, count(*) as cnt,
             max(count(*)) over (partition by prod) as max_cnt
      from t
      group by prod, amount
     ) pa
where max_cnt = 1;
```

These returns the same results on your data.  It is unclear to me which you would want if a `prod` had some duplicates and some unique amounts.

Or alternatively, if you just want the products (and not the amounts):

```
select prod
from t
group by prd
having count(*) = count(distinct amount);
```

Comment: i want where prod is the same but have different values

Comment: @Netfoxf . . . That is the second and third queries in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple with EXISTS:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where prod = t.prod and amount <> t.amount
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=91292fe04d9627ba54ad64b6b1ad7dbd).
Results:

```
>    PROD | AMOUNT
> ------: | -----:
> 1100005 |     25
> 1100005 |     15
> 1100005 |     10
> 1100002 |      7
> 1100002 |      8
> 1100002 |      9
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use analytic functions to do it in a single table scan:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( Prod, Amount ) AS 
SELECT 1100005, 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1100005, 15 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1100005, 25 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1100001, 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1100001, 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1100001, 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1100002,  9 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1100002,  8 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1100002,  7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1100003, 54 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1100003, 54 FROM DUAL
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT prod,
       amount
FROM   (
  SELECT prod,
         amount,
         COUNT( * ) OVER ( PARTITION BY Prod, Amount ) AS num_per_amount_prod,
         COUNT( DISTINCT Amount ) OVER ( PARTITION BY Prod ) AS num_amount_per_prod 
  FROM   table_name
)
WHERE  num_amount_per_prod > 1
AND    num_per_amount_prod = 1
```

**Output**:

> ```
>    PROD | AMOUNT
> ------: | -----:
> 1100002 |      7
> 1100002 |      8
> 1100002 |      9
> 1100005 |     10
> 1100005 |     15
> 1100005 |     25
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8db9cd52342db941a1ad96c8af7b5396)*